# Android: Help create progress bar while injecting sql

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am doing some injections to sql, about a hundred on first launch.  it doesn't take that long but i want a progress bar while the app is injecting data.

This is my code but progress bar doesn't appear, only black screen.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        boolean firstStart = settings.getBoolean("firstStart", true);        

        if(firstStart) {                  
         ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(myInject.this, "", "Please wait.", true);

            addInjection("The quick brown fox"); // about a hundred of these injections

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
         editor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
         editor.commit();

         dialog.dismiss(); //if i remove this i can see the progress dialog but wont close.
}
```

Comment: try addInjection in different thread. my guess is that it's blocking main thread from updating UI

Answer (score 1):

You will be running the operation on the UI Thread doing it this way. Take a look at running the 'inject' code within an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

It's worth having a read up on the developer site about not running tasks on the UI Thread.

Comment: I would add that the default progress is a circle going round and round. To show a horizontal bar would mean using STYLE_HORIZONTAL and calling incrementProgressBy(amount) in the background. This can't be done during a commit() because this is an atomic operation. So if I were you I would stick with the round thing.